# SDL Keyboard Handling.

Tags: sdl-2

SDL is a hardware abstraction layer, so it's understandable that it would map whatever the local system keys are onto a virtual keyboard.
Their wiki has this entry; https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode

But it never seems to take modifier keys into account when reporting the event, so that this code:

```
if(e.type==SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
    std::cout << SDL_GetKeyName(e.key.keysym.sym) << ":" << e.key.keysym.sym << std::endl;
}
```

Generates this result: (UK Keyboard)

Input: 1 causes output: 1:49

Input: 2 causes output: 2:50

Input: 3 causes output: 3:51

Input: 4 causes output: 4:52

Input: Shift+1 (!) causes output: 1:49

Input: Shift+2 (") causes output: 2:50

Input: Shift+3 (£) causes output: 3:51

Input: Shift+4 ($) causes output: 4:52

Yes, I understand that I can do something like this; SDL_Keymod _keystate = SDL_GetModState(); And take each key case by case. But that would limit it to my keyboard layoyt, would be ugly code, and quite frankly would make almost everything on this page worthless; https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode.

So. What am I missing, it obviously isn't applying modifiers by default? Is there a way to get it do so?

Comment: The function reports what key is pressed, not whatever secondary function the modifier applies. It's pretty standard at that. If you want "text" input, checking scan codes is too low-level.

Comment: I've gathered that. Is there a nice way to get whatever symbol is being represented by key+modifier? It seems strange having a load of scancodes that could never be reported as they are not the primary function of a key.

Comment: You didn't add a tag for a specific language, but I suppose it's C++. In plain C, you can use `getch` - but it halts your program, and checking if there is a key "waiting" is OS dependent.

Comment: [`SDL_StartTextInput()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_StartTextInput) & co.?  [More info](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials/TextInput).

Comment: I'll have to experiment wth that genpfault. I am fairly new to SDL, I am writting a text editor using it. The way I am doing it now is awful. I have a different table for each modifier or modifier combination, which I then hash into using the keycodes, translating to my own enum type for characters; which my program then handles else where.

Comment: @RadLexus Using `getch()` in the SDL event loop is really bad advice. Like you say it blocks. It is also not available on all platforms.